# Get Greatest Value in Array from CSV

Tags: arrays, powershell, measure

I have a csv where I have keys who have numbers assigned to them. When I add a key to the csv it will be assigned the next value.

My code does all of this except my calculation is wrong due to the fact that I cannot get the code to return the maximum value of the numbers already assigned.

my csv looks like:

```
Key,Count
9383, T-1
V-102,T-2
V-4982,T-65
85712, T-13
```

My code is:

```
$num = Import-Csv "$file1.csv" | Foreach {"$($_.Count)"}

for ($i=0; $i -lt $num.Count; $i++) 
{
     [string]$assignednumbers = $num[$i]

      #Remove T in front of numbers
      [string]$prefix = "T-"
      if ($assignednumbers.StartsWith($prefix)) 
      {
         $assignednumbers = $assignednumbers.Replace($prefix, [string]::Empty)
   }

    $greatestvalue = ([int]$assignednumbers | Measure -Maximum).Maximum
}
```

I am having issues with the line 
`$greatestvalue = ([int]$assignednumbers | Measure -Maximum).Maximum`
When I call `$greatestvalue` with just `$greatestvalue = [int]$assignednumbers | Measure -Maximum` I get a list of maximum properties for each item in my csv. It is supposed to return a value of 65.

This is where I ask for the number to add and add it to the csv (**no issues here**)

```
#which key do you want to add
$key = Read-Host "Please Input new Key"

#getting t number
$addingnum = $greatestvalue + 1
$newnumber = "T-$addingnum"


#Get new key information
if ($key -gt 0)
{
[string]$key =$key
write-host -foregroundcolor green "The new Key is $key and has been assigned $newnumber"
}

#add vkey from input to csv
$NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $newvkey,$newnumber
$NewLine | add-content -path "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite your `$greatestvalue` every time. You need to define it outside of cycle and change only if the current value is greater than the one you already have from previous iteration:

```
$num = Import-Csv "E:\1.csv" | Foreach {"$($_.Count)"}
$greatestvalue = 0
for ($i=0; $i -lt $num.Count; $i++) 
{
   [string]$assignednumbers = $num[$i]

    #Remove T in front of numbers
    [string]$prefix = "T-"
    if ($assignednumbers.StartsWith($prefix)) 
    {
       $assignednumbers = $assignednumbers.Replace($prefix, [string]::Empty)
 }
if ($greatestvalue -lt ([int]$assignednumbers | Measure -Maximum).Maximum)
  {
    $greatestvalue = ([int]$assignednumbers | Measure -Maximum).Maximum
  }
}
$greatestvalue
```

Comment: One look and you figured it out just like that. Ha! Thanks that worked liked a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get maximum of one number. And $greatestvalue just gets last value assigned. To fix it, change

```
$greatestvalue = ([int]$assignednumbers | Measure -Maximum).Maximum
```

to

```
if ($greatestvalue -lt [int]$assignednumbers) {
    $greatestvalue = $assignednumbers
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing something to that effect, but couldn't get the statement together